# Why won't the aside tag be on the same line as the article tag?

Tags: html

I am writing some code for an assignment and I am having trouble getting the aside to be on the same level as the article. I have provided an image of what i am trying to make and this is the code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("stars.jpg");
  font-family: arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px
}

header {
  background-image: url("banner.jpg");
}

nav {
  text-align: center
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14pt;
  border-right: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px
}

a:hover {
  color: #dedede
}

footer {
  text-align: center
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center
}

aside {
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #6c8cd5;
  width: 20%
}

section {
  background-color: #2a4480
}

article {
  width: 65%
}
```

```html
<header style="height:250px;">[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbZov.jpg)
</header>
<nav style="background-color:#444444">
  <a href="salyut.html">Salyut Program</a>
  <a href="skylab.html">Skylab</a>
  <a href="mir.html">Mir</a>
  <a href="iss.html">International Space Station</a>
</nav>
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>Start of the Space Race</h1>
    <p>Following the fall of Nazi Germany the United States and Soviet Union both sought after a common prize... Wernher von Braun. Von Braun was considered the best in the field of rocket science and was the developer of the V2 rocket. The V2 had a very
      short range by today's standards, but was the first rocket to reach space. Von Braun surrendered to the United States and agreed to use his knowledge of rocket science to develop the American space program. The Soviet Union was able to acquire much
      of Von Braun's documentation, and with that they were able to create the first intercontinental missile capable of travelling over 4000 miles from the USSR to Washington DC. Despite Von Braun's expertise in rocket science he was kept out of the
      rocket development program because of his Nazi affiliation during the war.</p>
    <p>On October 4, 1957 the Soviet Union launched Sputnik which was the first man made satellite to orbit the earth. This was the event that struck fear into the minds of many Americans. It was the first time in history that any location in the United
      States mainland was vulnerable to attack by the Soviet Union. In response the United States Navy developed and attempted to launch its own satellite called Vanguard which exploded on the launch pad. With this event, the US Government made the decision
      to bring Von Braun into the space program and 5 weeks later the US launched its first successful satellite called Jupiter C.</p>
    <p>Yuri Gagarin was launched on April 12, 1961 by the Soviet Union making him the first man in space. However on May 5, 1961 Alan Sheppard became first American into space. Americans were tired of coming in second to the Soviet therefore John F. Kennedy
      declared that the United States would be the first to make it to the Moon and Von Braun's talents were utilized in the development of the Mercury, Gemini, and Apollo programs. On July 20th, 1969 Apollo 11 landed on the moon making Neil Armstrong
      the first person to set foot on the moon. At this point the United States pulled ahead of the Soviet Union.</p>
    <p>The Soviet's answer to the US Saturn rocket program was the N1 rocket. Unfortunately their first test launch exploded upon its launch ultimately ending the race for the moon for the Soviet Union. Upon reaching the moon, the next goal was orbital outposts,
      or space stations, was set into motion.</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <figure>
      <img src="sputnik1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <figcaption>Sputnik</figcaption>
      <figure>
        <img src="jupiterC.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </figure>
      <figcaption>Jupiter C</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </aside>
  <footer style="background-color:#6c8cd">
    <p>IE Class</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

I have tried to change where the float css is and try to use some position css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use `float` for `aside`, move the `aside` element to the *start*  of the `section` tag, i.e., before the `article` at whose side it should be placed (in the following example the CSS is unchanged, only the HTML is modfied concerning the order of elements):

```css
    body {
      background-image: url("stars.jpg");
      font-family: arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 15px
    }
    
    header {
      background-image: url("banner.jpg");
    }
    
    nav {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 14pt;
      border-right: solid;
      border-right-width: 1px
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: #dedede
    }
    
    footer {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    figcaption {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    aside {
      float: right;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #6c8cd5;
      width: 20%
    }
    
    section {
      background-color: #2a4480
    }
    
    article {
      width: 65%
    }
```

```html
  <header style="height:250px;">[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbZov.jpg)
  </header>
  <nav style="background-color:#444444">
    <a href="salyut.html">Salyut Program</a>
    <a href="skylab.html">Skylab</a>
    <a href="mir.html">Mir</a>
    <a href="iss.html">International Space Station</a>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <aside>
      <figure>
        <img src="sputnik1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <figcaption>Sputnik</figcaption>
        <figure>
          <img src="jupiterC.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </figure>
        <figcaption>Jupiter C</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </aside>
    <article>
      <h1>Start of the Space Race</h1>
      <p>Following the fall of Nazi Germany the United States and Soviet Union both sought after a common prize... Wernher von Braun. Von Braun was considered the best in the field of rocket science and was the developer of the V2 rocket. The V2 had a very
        short range by today's standards, but was the first rocket to reach space. Von Braun surrendered to the United States and agreed to use his knowledge of rocket science to develop the American space program. The Soviet Union was able to acquire
        much of Von Braun's documentation, and with that they were able to create the first intercontinental missile capable of travelling over 4000 miles from the USSR to Washington DC. Despite Von Braun's expertise in rocket science he was kept out
        of the rocket development program because of his Nazi affiliation during the war.</p>
      <p>On October 4, 1957 the Soviet Union launched Sputnik which was the first man made satellite to orbit the earth. This was the event that struck fear into the minds of many Americans. It was the first time in history that any location in the United
        States mainland was vulnerable to attack by the Soviet Union. In response the United States Navy developed and attempted to launch its own satellite called Vanguard which exploded on the launch pad. With this event, the US Government made the
        decision to bring Von Braun into the space program and 5 weeks later the US launched its first successful satellite called Jupiter C.</p>
      <p>Yuri Gagarin was launched on April 12, 1961 by the Soviet Union making him the first man in space. However on May 5, 1961 Alan Sheppard became first American into space. Americans were tired of coming in second to the Soviet therefore John F. Kennedy
        declared that the United States would be the first to make it to the Moon and Von Braun's talents were utilized in the development of the Mercury, Gemini, and Apollo programs. On July 20th, 1969 Apollo 11 landed on the moon making Neil Armstrong
        the first person to set foot on the moon. At this point the United States pulled ahead of the Soviet Union.</p>
      <p>The Soviet's answer to the US Saturn rocket program was the N1 rocket. Unfortunately their first test launch exploded upon its launch ultimately ending the race for the moon for the Soviet Union. Upon reaching the moon, the next goal was orbital
        outposts, or space stations, was set into motion.</p>
    </article>
        <footer style="background-color:#6c8cd">
      <p>IE Class</p>
    </footer>
  </section>
```

In general I would rather recommend using flexbox for placing these elements next to each other instead of using float...